# Sending Request Using CURL Command and getting only a variable value from response using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, jenkins, curl, groovy

**My Curl request :**

```
curl -u "YOUR_USERNAME:YOUR_ACCESS_KEY" \
-X GET "https://api-cloud.browserstack.com/app-automate/sessions/22dbfb187486090d974a11ac91t65722988e0705.json"
```

---

**The Response I get :**

```
{
  "automation_session": {
    "name": "login_test",
    "duration": 39,
    "os": "android",
    "os_version": "9.0",
    "browser_version": "app",
    "browser": null,
    "device": "OnePlus 6T",
    "status": "passed",
    "hashed_id": "22dbfb187486090d974a11ac91t65722988e0705",
    "reason": "CLIENT_STOPPED_SESSION",
    "build_name": "SampleBuild",
    "project_name": "SampleProject",
    "logs": "https://app-automate.browserstack.com/builds/g0726012b6rb0a4c79122d6048c7b8767677ad61/sessions/22dbfb187486090d974a11ac91t65722988e0705/logs",
    "browser_url": "https://app-automate.browserstack.com/builds/g0726012b6rb0a4c79122d6048c7b8767677ad61/sessions/22dbfb187486090d974a11ac91t65722988e0705",
    "public_url": "https://app-automate.browserstack.com/builds/g0726012b6rb0a4c79122d6048c7b8767677ad61/sessions/22dbfb187486090d974a11ac91t65722988e0705?auth_token=9876563e667cd765467e6fea5a834121e568be899505699b",
    "appium_logs_url": "https://api.browserstack.com/app-automate/builds/g0726012b6rb0a4c79122d6048c7b8767677ad61/sessions/22dbfb187486090d974a11ac91t65722988e0705/appiumlogs",
    "video_url": "https://app-automate.browserstack.com/sessions/22dbfb187486090d974a11ac91t65722988e0705/video?token=ZnN6cGt1WTY4UlJrdTVzcE5xcGhWTldvZGVlRydys4aWc9PSaHVkTS84UnNhdU54aWtmVU9lWHFPVWt3TM5UjJXdkNmSjdHUGxuLzBmQWFXamcyS3htM3l0tc0xZempkdnVlQ3BrN1A5OWFILzNZdz09--37203d41d45d3d42e1fb75266e527721af3ab65d&source=rest_api&diff=60060.827966758",
    "device_logs_url": "https://api.browserstack.com/app-automate/builds/g0726012b6rb0a4c79122d6048c7b8767677ad61/sessions/22dbfb187486090d974a11ac91t65722988e0705/devicelogs",
    "app_details": {
      "app_url": "bs://c8ddcb5649a8280ca800075bfd8f151115bba6b3",
      "app_name": "com.sample.loginapplication",
      "app_version": "1.0",
      "app_custom_id": "LoginApp",
      "uploaded_at": "2020-09-09T18:14:20.000Z"
    }
  }
}
```

From the Above Value Only require
public_url in a java Script Variable to display the same

---

**Alternatively Please also suggest if its possible in Groovy Script For Pipeline.**

Comment: You mean like `response.automation_session.publicUrl`?

Comment: Is there a question here?

Comment: The question here is how do I run [**My Curl request**] in JavaScript  then store the public URL in a data base.

`var publicurl : response.automation_session.publicUrl`

[_curl command which has access key and username_]

Comment: @SaurabhKawli  Best I can do is give you the JavaScript.  I do not use third party add ons.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the JavaScript:
Untested.

```
fetch('https://api-cloud.browserstack.com/app-automate/sessions/22dbfb187486090d974a11ac91t65722988e0705.json', {
    headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Basic ' + btoa('YOUR_USERNAME:YOUR_ACCESS_KEY')
    }
});
.then((response) => response.json())
.then((data) => console.log(data));
```